# ireports disregarding my settings

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

I am currently using an XML datasource and I have the date patterns as well as the number pattern set up as dd/mm/yyyy and #,##0.00 respectively, however the data I am pulling from the fields with Xpath is not following this pattern.

an example of a date I am catching is : 2014-02-12 16:00:15 while a price will appear as 40.0000000000.

I also clicked on the aformentioned fields and went into properties, and under pattern I changed it to currency as the numbers refer to prices and set decimals to 2, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial & error I came to this method that worked wonders.

```
new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{Precio_unidad-price_unit}))
```

setting this in the TexytFieldExpression will actually do what is neccesary, the report now prints the correct number of decimals.